# How do u define decimal 19.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.8

I have written an Online Store with Laravel 5.8 and in this project I want to define `amount` column at `user_transactions` table with **Decimal 19.2** data type.

So I opened up `phpmyadmin` and changed the data type to `decimal`.

Now I need to know how to define **Decimal(19.2)** in both `phpmyadmin` and Laravel Migration.

I already know how to use Decimal data types in Laravel by saying:

```
$table->decimal('amount');
```

But where does the `19.2` define?

Comment: What do you mean? If you already set `decimal(19,2)` on mysql table column, it doesn't matter how many decimal the value for insert is... it's always being stored according to the column defined decimal value. [See this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eebf72e6e487a9d62b4c4712e245ad8b)

Comment: `decimal('field', 3, 1)` means total of 3 digits including 1 decimal digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe you are talking about precision and scale here. you can declare the column with

```
$table->decimal('amount', 19, 2);
```

from the docs this is

> DECIMAL equivalent column with a precision (total digits) and scale (decimal digits).

as for the phpMyAdmin, choose type `DECIMAL` and Length/Values `19,2`. this will do the same. but don't use phpMyAdmin directly. use migration to modify/add columns to the table.